# Difference between converting a list to a new type using List.from vs List.map?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I want to convert following collection to `List<int>`,

```dart
final listDouble = <double>[1.0, 2.0];
```

I can either use

```dart
final listInt = List<int>.from(listDouble);
```

or

```dart
final listInt = listDouble.map<int>((e) => e.toInt()).toList();
```

Is there any difference between two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the laziness mentioned by [iDecode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61037277/179715), you should be aware that the `List<E>.from` way isn't technically correct for your case.

[`List<E>.from`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.from.html) requires that the argument list have elements of type `E`, and `int`s aren't `double`s. (Note that it will work for web platforms (e.g. DartPad), where Dart is transpiled to JavaScript, because all JavaScript numbers are  IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers.  If you try it in a Dart VM, however, it will throw an exception.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have converted the list from `double` to `int`, in that case it would work, correct?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName It doesn't matter whether you convert from `double` to `int` or `int` to `double`.  Neither derives from the other, so they aren't implicitly convertible.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I'd like a like a little more explanation of your line `List<E>.from requires that the argument list have elements of type E`?

Comment: I don't know how I can explain it any more; it means exactly what it says.  `List<int>.from` requires that the argument already be a collection of `int`s. `List<int>.from` is basically the same as `List<int>.of` except `.from` is from before Dart had compile-time type-checking, so `.from` will fail at runtime if the argument type is wrong.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of your detailed explanation. Thank. you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.

`map()` returns a lazy `Iterable`, meaning that the supplied function is called only when the elements are iterated unlike `List.from()`.